# Better way to check object property and call a method

Tags: javascript, typeof

*(Sorry if it was queried previously, I didnt found it)*

I used to **check** if an object and method exists and **call** it in this way:

```
 obj && obj.method && obj.method()
```

But, I suspect that some cases this are making some troubles on IE..

Do I need check it using `typeof undefined/function/object`  ?

```
 typeof obj === 'object' && typeof obj.method === 'function' && obj.method()
```

I would like to know what is the securest and clearest style to code it.

Comment: Only if you suspect `obj.method` might not be a function.

Comment: What error are you getting in IE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To ensure that you can properly execute a method named `method` on an object named `object`, this is the shortest safe check:

```
if (typeof object === 'object' && typeof object.method === 'function') {
    object.method();
}
```

You need to first check that the object exists, then make sure that the property you want is a function. Any other checks are redundant.

Note this falls apart if you have something weird like a number `0` or boolean `false` with a `method` property you're trying to execute, but you may have larger problems if you're appending properties to booleans and numbers.

Comment: If `object` is not defined, it will raise a `ReferenceError` exception.

Comment: Now it has nothing different with the OP's solution :)

Comment: if object is not defined why is not evaluated as false? what is the difference again var object = object || {}; ?

Comment: @MartinBorthiry there's a difference between *being undefined* (which will throw an exception if you put it in an `if` statement, which the edit protects against) and *having the value undefined* (which evaluates to `false` in an `if` statement).